# Installation conflict for gcc-multilib and gcc-9-aarch64-linux-gnu on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on an x86 labtop, and I try to install 'gcc for aarch64' (cross-compilation) and `gcc-multilib` with the following command:

```
sudo apt install gcc-9-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-multilib
```

However, I got the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-9-aarch64-linux-gnu : Conflicts: gcc-multilib but 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 gcc-multilib : Conflicts: gcc-9-aarch64-linux-gnu
                Conflicts: gcc-9-aarch64-linux-gnu:i386
```

Is there a way to install the cross-compilation compiler and the gcc-multilib at the same time?

Comment: This is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1300211